# specify column limit using string builder?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I've a Datagridview,from which i need to read values from each row to specific columns of a notepad with a column limit of 200.Can it be done with String Builder??

Comment: Posting some code that shows what you have tried would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Question is not very clear... 
Anyway, if you got a string you can extract the first 200 characters using the SubString method:

```
var result = yourString.SubString(0,199)
```